# TCP Multiple Connections vs 1 connection (Application Managing)

Tags: sockets, tcp

I need some advice... I'm building a desktop application where every window needs constant input from the user (events like click, typing, mouse move) to be sent to the server. The server also sends constant feedback like (refresh some data in the dialog, text, new objects, etc)

First I thought I would use HTTP, but now choose to use plain TCP.

**My question is:** Should I use one TCP connection and handle all info from the server at "Application Layer", or should I create multiple connections (like one for each window and let the OS handle the multiple TCP pipes) ?

I can programming any of these 2 ideas, but who would be more efficient in terms of performance and bandwidth?

## Update 1

- It would be like 2000 clients using the system at same time
- Each client would use 2~3 windows at same time

Comment: How many clients are going to connecting to this server?

Comment: Hi Floegipoky! I will be like 2000 clients, each one it's going to use 2~3 windows. Thanks

Comment: Hmm, that's kind of borderline for initial requirements.  If you can guarantee those numbers, you will be ok.  But if there's any possibility that you might have more users and more windows, you could easily start bumping up against limitations.  I'd say implement the connection logic on the client in such a way that you could add more servers to your backend without the clients needing to update, just in case.

Comment: Yes, I as thinking about a distributed server. Multiple VMs with ServerApp running and each sharing a common database (Oracle or MySQL or SQLServer)

Answer (score 1):

This depends too much on your specific application, but where possible I'd pick multiple connections, it has multiple advantages:

- No head-of-line blocking between multiple components (windows in your case).
- Multiprocessing/multithreading available even on socket layer (e.g. you can have 1 thread/socket).
- You don't need to build a multiplexer protocol atop of TCP yourself.

The only reasons why you wouldn't want to do this:

- You're short on ephemeral ports. This is usually not an issue unless you're talking about tens of thousands of long-lived sockets or you're working behind some very restrictive NAT device.
- The OS overhead (memory/processing power) per socket is non-neglible. I'd be surprised if this would be true for any decent modern OS, but measuring is knowing.

Comment: Thank you. Im looking forward to use multiple connections, I'm just afraid from the server-side perspective, 6000 connections alive can be a issue?

Comment: @user3558040 shouldn't be, any decent server platform should be able to handle that, in terms of socket resources anyway :). The server hasn't the problem of ephemeral ports and typically you have a bigger say in the OS as to avoid socket overhead issues.